# eclipse AVD keeps crashing on nexus 5

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device, nexus-5

I am trying to run this simple map app that was tutorial, on my nexus 5. The problem is, it  keeps crashing and gives me this error "Unfortunately, Map has stopped"
this is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.map"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
      <uses-permission   android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
      <!-- External storage for caching. -->
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
      <!-- My Location -->
      <uses-permission              android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

      <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
      <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

       <!-- ** You need to replace the key below with your own key. **
     The example key below will not be accepted because it is not linked to the
     certificate which you will use to sign this application.
     See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start
     for instructions on how to get your own key. -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="A54368DTT97nHkyS_6OARPqIn4uNtRc-snMONLM"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.map.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

This is my MainActivity
    package com.example.map;

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity implements             OnMapClickListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng position) {

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(position).
                      icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

}

}
```

Can anyone help me out what am doing wrong here !!!

this is my log

```
    03-25 13:49:21.962: I/GCM(3819): GCM message GSYNC_TICKLE               0:1395769762708048%0#e7a71353318775cf
03-25 13:49:21.982: I/SubscribedFeeds(3819): Received message
03-25 13:49:22.022: V/Zygote(4666): Switching descriptor 32 to /dev/null
03-25 13:49:22.022: V/Zygote(4666): Switching descriptor 10 to /dev/null
03-25 13:49:22.022: I/ActivityManager(685): Start proc com.google.android.gm for service com.google.android.gm/.provider.MailSyncAdapterService: pid=4666 uid=10067 gids={50067, 3003, 1028, 1015}
03-25 13:49:22.042: D/AndroidRuntime(4663): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
03-25 13:49:22.042: D/AndroidRuntime(4663): CheckJNI is OFF
03-25 13:49:22.052: D/dalvikvm(4663): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/telephony-msim.jar'
03-25 13:49:22.052: D/dalvikvm(4663): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
03-25 13:49:22.052: D/dalvikvm(4663): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
03-25 13:49:22.052: D/dalvikvm(4663): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
03-25 13:49:22.052: D/dalvikvm(4663): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
03-25 13:49:22.052: D/dalvikvm(4663): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
03-25 13:49:22.072: D/dalvikvm(4663): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 180 unimplemented (abstract) methods
03-25 13:49:22.132: W/GAV2(4666): Thread[main,5,main]: Need to call initialize() and be in fallback mode to start dispatch.
03-25 13:49:22.202: D/AndroidRuntime(4663): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
03-25 13:49:22.212: D/AndroidRuntime(4663): Shutting down VM
03-25 13:49:22.212: D/jdwp(4663): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
03-25 13:49:22.212: D/dalvikvm(4663): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-25 13:49:22.302: I/Gmail(4666): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: queueing
03-25 13:49:22.312: I/Gmail(4666): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: queueing
03-25 13:49:22.322: I/Gmail(4666): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: running
03-25 13:49:22.322: I/Gmail(4666): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: running
03-25 13:49:22.342: I/Gmail(4666): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: queueing
03-25 13:49:22.342: I/Gmail(4666): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 835367, normalSync: true
03-25 13:49:22.372: I/Gmail(4666): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: queueing
03-25 13:49:22.392: I/Gmail(4666): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: running
03-25 13:49:22.392: I/Gmail(4666): calculateUnknownSyncRationalesAndPurgeInBackground: running
03-25 13:49:22.472: D/ConnectivityService(685): handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=1, condition=100, published condition=0
03-25 13:49:22.492: W/GLSUser(3819): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
03-25 13:49:22.682: D/AndroidRuntime(4705): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
03-25 13:49:22.682: D/AndroidRuntime(4705): CheckJNI is OFF
03-25 13:49:22.692: D/dalvikvm(4705): Unable to stat classpath element '/system/framework/telephony-msim.jar'
03-25 13:49:22.692: D/dalvikvm(4705): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
03-25 13:49:22.692: D/dalvikvm(4705): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
03-25 13:49:22.702: D/dalvikvm(4705): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
03-25 13:49:22.702: D/dalvikvm(4705): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
03-25 13:49:22.702: D/dalvikvm(4705): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
03-25 13:49:22.722: D/dalvikvm(4705): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 180 unimplemented (abstract) methods
03-25 13:49:22.852: D/AndroidRuntime(4705): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
03-25 13:49:22.862: I/ActivityManager(685): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.map/.MainActivity} from pid 4705
03-25 13:49:22.872: D/AndroidRuntime(4705): Shutting down VM
03-25 13:49:22.872: D/jdwp(4705): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
03-25 13:49:22.872: D/dalvikvm(4705): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-25 13:49:22.872: V/Zygote(4719): Switching descriptor 32 to /dev/null
03-25 13:49:22.872: V/Zygote(4719): Switching descriptor 10 to /dev/null
03-25 13:49:22.882: D/dalvikvm(4719): Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-25 13:49:22.882: I/ActivityManager(685): Start proc com.example.map for activity com.example.map/.MainActivity: pid=4719 uid=10132 gids={50132, 3003, 1028, 1015}
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719): Failed to inflate
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at com.example.map.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5232)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.eb(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
03-25 13:49:23.022: E/ActivityThread(4719):     ... 20 more
03-25 13:49:23.022: D/AndroidRuntime(4719): Shutting down VM
03-25 13:49:23.022: W/dalvikvm(4719): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414f0c80)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719): Process: com.example.map, PID: 4719
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.map/com.example.map.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.example.map.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5232)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     ... 11 more
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.eb(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
03-25 13:49:23.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4719):     ... 20 more
03-25 13:49:23.032: W/ActivityManager(685):   Force finishing activity com.example.map/.MainActivity
03-25 13:49:23.382: I/Gmail(4666): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 835436, normalSync: true
03-25 13:49:23.442: W/GLSUser(3819): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
03-25 13:49:23.552: W/ActivityManager(685): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4207c9c8 u0 com.example.map/.MainActivity t5 f}
03-25 13:49:23.642: I/ActivityManager(1390): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@417862e8 time:246021
03-25 13:49:23.872: I/ActivityManager(685): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{41932930 u0 com.teslacoilsw.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher t1} time:246251
03-25 13:49:24.492: I/Gmail(4666): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 835436, normalSync: true
03-25 13:49:24.492: I/Gmail(4666): lowestBackward conversation id 0
03-25 13:49:24.562: I/Gmail(4666): Sending provider changed intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED dat=content://gmail-ls/unread/^sq_ig_i_personal (has extras) }
03-25 13:49:24.622: I/NotifUtils(4666): Validating Notification, mapSize: 1 getAttention: true ignoreUnobtrusive: true
03-25 13:49:24.652: I/NotifUtils(4666): Showing notification with unreadCount of 1 and unseenCount of 1
03-25 13:49:24.712: I/NotifUtils(4666): Account: -959915502 vibrate: false
03-25 13:49:24.712: I/NotifUtils(4666): New email in -959915502 vibrateWhen: false, playing notification: content://settings/system/notification_sound
03-25 13:49:24.842: I/ActivityManager(685): Killing 4477:com.android.keychain/1000 (adj 15): empty #17
03-25 13:49:24.942: V/Zygote(4743): Switching descriptor 32 to /dev/null
03-25 13:49:24.942: V/Zygote(4743): Switching descriptor 10 to /dev/null
03-25 13:49:24.952: I/ActivityManager(685): Start proc android.process.media for content provider com.android.providers.media/.MediaProvider: pid=4743 uid=10005 gids={50005, 1028, 1015, 1023, 1024, 2001, 3003, 3007}
03-25 13:49:25.122: I/ActivityManager(685): Killing 4508:com.google.android.gms.drive/u0a15 (adj 15): empty #17
03-25 13:49:25.132: I/MediaFocusControl(685):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@42749890
03-25 13:49:25.142: E/MediaPlayer(1107): Should have subtitle controller already set
03-25 13:49:25.142: D/audio_hw_primary(230): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: )
03-25 13:49:25.532: I/Icing(3941): Indexing B71FF803A8F9FEF55B46FCC19DB7D633C0DCBD23 from com.google.android.gm
03-25 13:49:25.682: I/Icing(3941): Indexing done B71FF803A8F9FEF55B46FCC19DB7D633C0DCBD23
03-25 13:49:25.692: I/ActivityManager(685): Killing 3909:com.android.voicedialer/u0a14 (adj 15): empty #17
03-25 13:49:26.482: I/MediaFocusControl(685):  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@42749890
03-25 13:49:27.142: W/GAV2(4666): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), will retry.
03-25 13:49:27.142: W/ActivityManager(685): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) } U=0: not found
03-25 13:49:27.182: I/GAV2(4666): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
03-25 13:49:30.842: I/PowerManagerService(685): Going to sleep due to screen timeout...
03-25 13:49:31.182: D/SurfaceFlinger(227): Screen released, type=0 flinger=0xf450
03-25 13:49:31.182: D/qdhwcomposer(227): hwc_blank: Blanking display: 0
03-25 13:49:31.232: D/NfcService(1343): NFC-C OFF
03-25 13:49:31.482: D/qdhwcomposer(227): hwc_blank: Done blanking display: 0
03-25 13:49:31.482: D/SurfaceControl(685): Excessive delay in blankDisplay() while turning screen off: 304ms
03-25 13:49:31.482: E/PowerHAL(685): sync_thread: failed to send: No such file or directory
03-25 13:49:32.152: W/ActivityManager(685): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) } U=0: not found
03-25 13:49:32.162: W/GAV2(4666): Thread[Service Reconnect,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), using local store.
03-25 13:49:32.892: E/WindowManager(685): Starting window AppWindowToken{424cb708 token=Token{419c4548 ActivityRecord{4207c9c8 u0 com.example.map/.MainActivity t5}}} timed out
03-25 13:49:33.642: W/ActivityManager(685): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{4207c9c8 u0 com.example.map/.MainActivity t5 f}
03-25 13:49:36.332: D/audio_hw_primary(230): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: )
03-25 13:49:36.382: E/KeyguardHostView(1107): Error when trying to bind default AppWidget: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a appwidget provider: ComponentInfo{/}
03-25 13:49:36.502: D/PhoneStatusBar(1107): disable: < EXPAND* icons alerts TICKER*       system_info BACK* HOME* RECENT* CLOCK* search >
```

Comment: Have you seen the `You need to replace the key below with your own key` comment in the manifest?

Comment: yeah i have changed the key in manifest...

Comment: this is the log that i could paste in here.. hope its the rightone ..

Comment: You need to fix your question title - you are either testing on an AVD (android **virtual** device, ie emulator) or on a Nexus 5 **phone** - but you can't be running on both **in the same trial**.

Comment: Perhaps the AVD is Nexus5-based? http://i.imgur.com/nvll9EU.png Although per op's description, this is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Your logcat says the following:

```
caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.
You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Simply place that last line within the `<application>` element of `AndroidManifest.xml`

See here for more information on the `<application>` tag:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Comment: i am still having the issue .. am i supposed to put the meta data after closing application </application> or on the top  of the page

Comment: Between `<application>` and `</application>`. I edited my answer with a link that can provide more information about the `<application>` tag.